# ¿"No lo es" con objeto femenino?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, género

En una frase como la siguiente

> Esta frase se parece a una frase bonita, pero no **lo** es.

¿Es correcto usar "no lo es" en vez de "no la es", suponiendo que en el segundo fragmento "la" referiría a "la frase"?  Creo que sí -- me suena natural y correcto -- pero en este momento me he quedado en blanco.

Comment: ¿Dudas de cómo etiquetar la pregunta? Debatámoslo en [¿Cómo deberíamos etiquetar las preguntas sobre pronombres 'la', 'le' y 'lo' y en las que se observa laísmo, leísmo o loísmo?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2924/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui - Creo que la adición de "género" no creará polémica.  (Sin tu comentario hubiera agregado "lo" pero si quieres esperar hasta tener un nuevo plan, bien, no lo pongo.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Según la NGLE ([37.1i](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SMIDbDgAsxPmtKvK)-[37.1k](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wnrspzWzJWTkNLhx)), los atributos de los verbos copulativos como *parecer* se sustituyen por el pronombre neutro *lo* independientemente de su género y número.

Comment: cabe indicar que solo se utiliza cuando el verbo copulativo esta actuando como tal, ejemplo : 

a karla "la" estan molestand;      
karla esta molesta, "lo esta"

Answer (score 4):

Aquí, usado para sustituir al atributo de la oración, *lo* actúa como un pronombre de género neutro invariable de tercera persona.

Unos ejemplos:

> —Las chicas eran *guapa̲s̲*, ¿verdad? —Sí, *lo* eran.
>
> —La chica era *guapa̲*, ¿verdad? —Sí, *lo* era.
>
> —Los chicos eran *guapo̲s̲*, ¿verdad? —Sí, *lo* eran.
>
> —El chico era *guapo̲*, ¿verdad? —Sí, *lo* era.

No es lo mismo que el *lo/la* de

- *verlo, lo dejó en la mesa [el libro]* etc
- *verla, la dejó en la mesa [la manzana]* etc
  <sub>(Pronombre personal masculino y neutro de objeto directo (acusativo), tercera persona del singular.)</sub>

o el *lo* de:

- *lo mismo, lo malo* etc
  <sub>(Artículo determinado de género neutro que se usa para sustantivar adjetivos o frases.)</sub>

Comment: la diferencia es el uso para atribuir propiedades (modo copulativo)

Comment: No entiendo esta parte: "verlo".  A menos que sea parte de una lista....